# Standard BC-API to post Sales Orders

Tags: api, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-business-central

Short Question:
I have been looking for a Standard Business Central API to post a Sales Order, but I wasn't able to find anything.

Do you know if I just haven't found it or if there really isn't any API for that scenario.

I am using this APIs:

```
https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v2.0/{{tenantid}}/{{environmentname}}/api/v2.0/companies({{companyid}})/{{element}}
```

There should be something like a bound action, but I can't really fit it in here.

Thanks for your replies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to post a Sales Order through the API.

The method to do this is called a `bound action`.

On the Sales Order API the bound action is called `ShipAndInvoice`.

To call it you make a `POST` request against this endpoint:

```
https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v2.0/{{tenantId}}/{{environmentName}}/api/v2.0/companies({companyId})/salesOrders({id})/Microsoft.NAV.shipAndInvoice
```

Note that the API endpoint is case sensitive.